# Codeigniter what is best way to use CSRF?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm not good in web security. Since I have started learning and using Codeigniter, I have read about Cross-site request forgery (CSRF), but I'm not sure how to use it.

Is CSRF in Codeigniter used on frontend form only, or every form frontend and backend I have created? I see other articles that it will cause a problem to who is using Ajax and other API like Facebook, etc...

Comment: You can see documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)

Comment: @AHJeebon just set $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE; and using form_open() tag does we need to validation it when send POST data to Controller or it auto check for us ?how it work pls explain if i get it wrong